# Is there a way to get all available arguments while executing a command? (Discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to add a role to a member when the command is executed as such: `.addrole @username <role-name>`. The following snippet works, however only the first word right after `@username` is taken as the role name. This means that role names with anything more than 1 word are not found. Would there be a way to get all the available words after `@username` and perform the role search with that?

```
if (!message.mentions.users.size) return message.reply('You need to tag a member in order to assign them a role!');

      const member = message.mentions.members.first();
      const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == args[1]);
      if(!role) return message.reply('The specified role was not found.');
      if(member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
        message.reply(`${member} already has the "${role.name}" role!`);
      }
      else {
        member.roles.add(role.id).then(() => {
          message.channel.send(`${member} was given the "${role.name}" role`);
        }).catch((e) => {console.log(e);});
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only taken the 2nd argument in using `args[1]`. The role your trying to add must contain multiple so you can't just use `args[1]`. You have to slice the first and join the rest of the arguments. The code below should work but let me know if you get any errors.

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == args.slice(1).join(' '));
```